# emacs regexp to match strings with first letter capitalized

Tags: emacs

In a lisp function I've got the following test with a regular expression that should match any string that starts with a capital letter:

```
(if (string-match "^[A-Z].+" my-string)
```

However this matches also the lower case starting strings. What am I missing here?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

From `string-match` description ( to show it type `C-h f` or `M-x describe-function` ):

```
(string-match REGEXP STRING &optional START)
```

> Return index of start of first match for REGEXP in STRING, or nil.
>   Matching ignores case if `case-fold-search' is non-nil.

Just set `case-fold-search` to `nil`.

```
(let ((case-fold-search nil))
 (string-match "^[A-Z].+"  my-string))
```

Answer (score 1):

Note that it's worse: it also matches `"...\nHello"` even though it starts with a dot, because `^` matches not just the beginning of the string, but also the beginning of any line inside that string.  The regexp-operator that only matches the beginning of a string is \`.  I recommend you use:

```
(let ((case-fold-search nil)) (string-match "\\`[[:upper:]]" my-string))
```